# Microsoft Visual Studio freezed and stopped working when I open properties from View Menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]I tried to installed old versions. And I also tried latest version. But it's not working. I'm using it on Windows 10 Professional Version. I've been working on it for like 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods here:

1. For example, I am using Visual Studio 2022, in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_e476ad3d\ComponentModelCache, please delete all files in ComponentModelCache and restart Visual Studio
2. Delete the .vs folder in the solution

**Note: AppData and .vs above but hidden folders**

Comment: I tried every possible ways but still Microsoft really sucks. It freezes, heavy-weight and takes long time in doing installation and uninstall. So, I'm now using IntelliJ Rider and it works like a charm. Thanks for your help anyway.